# Switch Controls Outlet, Not Ceiling Light

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

When we bought our house, the switch to the ceiling fan did not work, unless pushed to the side, or pushed in before being used. It seemed to be a simple enough task to replace the switch. However, the wires were not nicely labeled, and when installed, the ceiling light stays on while the outlets are controlled by the outlet. What I'd like to know is how to identify the "hot" wire coming to the room, and differentiate it from the "hot" wire the runs to the outlets and the "hot" wire that runs to the ceiling fan. My guess is that I switched the latter two.

Comment: A non contact voltage detector could be your firend to identify hot wires I have seen cheap ones under 5$ and high quality fluke models for under 20$ other than that a volt meter they usually cost more but there are cheap ones for around 20$ and better quality starts around 75$ .

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they're labeled. Besides ground, there are only 2 wires going to a switch, and a unit replacement of a switch only requires dealing with those two. Reversing them doesn't matter. Can you power off, unscrew the switch yokes, spread out the contents of the box to make it more visible (leave white and bare bundles in the back of the box), and shoot a picture?

Comment: Yes, can we have a photo showing what's in the box?